# Are Unused Portions of Table Expressions Calculated?

Tags: t-sql, sql-view

Suppose I have a SQL Server view defined as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW V_Test1 AS
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB
FROM Table1
```

and then I have another view defined as:

```
CREATE VIEW V_Test2 AS
SELECT ColumnA
FROM Table1
```

Would these 2 statements be equally optimized, considering that a view is merely a table expression, and ColumnB is not even called?  What if ColumnB wasn't in Table1 but rather the result of a complicated logic or call to another function?

```
SELECT ColumnA FROM V_Test1
SELECT ColumnA FROM V_Test2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in Microsoft SQL Server they will have identical execution plans. You can even write an expression that causes an error into ColumnB (for example "1/0"), it won't be executed.